# Combine 2 result sets into a single row

Tags: mysql

I have 2 result sets, how do i combine them such that they are in a single row?

```
    Result 1:

    North | South| East | West 
    ---------------------------
      5       0      0      5       

    SQL:
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'North' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS North,
        SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'South' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS South,
        SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'East' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS East,
        SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'West' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS West,
    FROM incident
    GROUP BY typeOfIncident
    HAVING typeOfIncident LIKE '%H1N5%';


    Result 2:

    North1 | South1 | East1 | West1 
    --------------------------------
      0       5         5       8       

    SQL:
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'North' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS North1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'South' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS South1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'East' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS East1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'West' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS West1,
    FROM incident
    GROUP BY typeOfIncident
    HAVING typeOfIncident LIKE 'Zombie%';


    OUTPUT:

    North | South | East | West | North1 | South1 | East1 | West1
    --------------------------------------------------------------
      5       0      0      5       0         5       5       8
```

I've tried using union, cross join etc. No results were returned. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN typeOfIncident LIKE '%H1N5%' AND 
                 region = 'North' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS North,
   SUM(CASE WHEN typeOfIncident LIKE '%H1N5%' AND 
                 region = 'South' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS South,
   SUM(CASE WHEN typeOfIncident LIKE '%H1N5%' AND 
                 region = 'East' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS East,
   SUM(CASE WHEN typeOfIncident LIKE '%H1N5%' AND 
              region = 'West' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS West,
   SUM(CASE WHEN typeOfIncident LIKE 'Zombie%' AND
                 region = 'North' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS North1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN typeOfIncident LIKE 'Zombie%' AND
                 region = 'South' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS South1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN typeOfIncident LIKE 'Zombie%' AND
                 region = 'East' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS East1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN typeOfIncident LIKE 'Zombie%' AND
                 region = 'West' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS West1
FROM incident
```